# How I can remove "-ms" style property in IE 11 with JS code?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How I can remove "-ms-overflow-x" style property in IE 11?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove the style? Is there any difference between IE and other browsers when applying the style? If so, I think you should overwrite the style in IE instead of removing it. Just as Diogo said, styles not defined inline can't be removed. You could made a minimal sample to reproduce the outcome of the styles, so that we can test in different browsers and see how to make it compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The `ms-overflow-x: auto` is the default option. In this case, it should be resetting some other `overflow` definition to this class. What you should think is: "What kind of overflow I want here?"

It can be `auto`, `none`, `scrollbar` or `-ms-autohiding-scrollbar`. And just set to it.

If you want to get the parent value (and probably the initial one), just use the `ms-overflow-x: inherit`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style

Comment: Have you tried to use css? Just create a new definition for this inside you css file and see if attends to you: something like: `.table-responsive { -ms-overflow-x: scrollbar }`. And a side note: styles that are not defined inline, cannot be removed, only overwritten. So, if you are going to overwrite anyway, go the easiest way.